# Does the chlorination of 4-methylcyclopentene generate two enantiomers or two diastereomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality, halogenation

Does the chlorination of 4-methylcyclopentene generate two enantiomers or two diastereomers?
[image]

I think it makes two enantiomers (or one pair of enantiomer) since the starting compound is achiral, but the answer key says it's two diastereomers.

When I tried making the products using molecular model kit, I think  I got enantiomers.
[image]

Comment: Under what conditions?

Comment: I'm taking a intro organic chemistry course so sorry if I'm not being specific enough. I'm pretty sure it's just supposed to be the reaction that forms a chloronium ion and undergoes anti addition.

Comment: You have a reaction that is not stereoselective. Such a reaction will produce something that is either achiral or racemic on an achiral reactant. Since there are two products here, they must be enantiomers and formed in equal amounts.

Comment: It is interesting when there are two diametric answers to a question.[Zhe's comment and KMT's answer] Agreed trans addition to a double bond gives RR or SS configurations about the vicinal carbons. The question is: Is there induced chirality in the carbon with the methyl group? [additional Question what is correct name for this compound?] My first impression is that the methyl carbon has two identical groups either a RR or a SS and is not chiral. [...] Hopefully someone knowledgeable will settle this dilemma and point out the fallacy or correctness in my, ZHe's, or KMT's analysis.

Answer (score 3):

For an anti addition, you get enantiomers (left two structures) in equal amounts. The enantiomers in the orientation shown are related by a mirror plane swapping left and right:

[image]

For a syn addition, you get achiral structures that are diastereomers (right two structures) in unequal amounts.

> [OP] I think it makes two enantiomers (or one pair of enantiomer) since the starting compound is achiral, but the answer key says it's two diastereomers.

If the question is about anti addition, as the OP mentions in the comments, then you get enantiomers.

> [Zhe in comments] You have a reaction that is not stereoselective. Such a reaction will produce something that is either achiral or racemic on an achiral reactant. Since there are two products here, they must be enantiomers and formed in equal amounts.

The syn addition seems to contradict that statement. You start with an achiral reactant, but you get a pair of achiral diastereomers, and not at equal amounts. It is true that in cases where you get enantiomers from non-chiral starting materials (like in the anti addition), it will be a racemic mixture (formed in equal amounts).

> [deleted answer] The two products formed will be considered enantiomers if the configuration of all the chiral carbons in the compound are different. But here only the carbons to which chlorine attaches have different configurations and not the carbon to which methyl is attached. Hence they will be diastereomers.

If you compare the first pair of structures in the figure above (the ones labeled anti addition), you might think they are diastereomers just by inspecting the wedges and dashes. However, if you rotate these structures around a vertical axis, the methyl group will now point downward while the chlorines point in the same direction as before the rotation, as the figure below illustrates. So the two structures in the box are identical, and if you compare the left structure with the right one in the box, you can see that they are enantiomers, related by a mirror plane parallel to the paper. Merely comparing wedges and dashes, you might think that the two structures in the box are diastereomers, but in fact they are identical.

[image]